# I want to update the environmental variable on a bot on Heroku but I get this error. Edit: Looked at the post tagged & it doesn't answer my question

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

My enviromental variable is called "GAMES_PLAYED",
I have this piece of code that is supposed to retrieve the environmental variable, add 1 to it, then save the environmental variable and it's new value.

```
gamesPlayed = os.environ.get("GAMES_PLAYED")
gamesPlayed = int(gamesPlayed) + 1
os.environ("GAMES_PLAYED") = str(gamesPlayed)
print(gamesPlayed)
```

I was sure it would update the variable but instead I get this error:

```
File "/app/code.py", line 1292
os.environ("GAMES_PLAYED") = str(gamesPlayed)
^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickArtner this is how I would update normal variables

Comment: `os.environ` is a dictionary and you have to use `[ ]` instead of `( )` to change value in dictionary.